# How to stop the Windows C library from converting "\r\n" to "\n" when reading a text file in C?

Tags: c, windows, newline

I have a normal text file that lines end with normal \r\n. However, when using 'open' and 'read', Windows convert all the \r\n to \n. I know this means I have to open the file in binary mode but the function 'open' doesn't give this option, it has only read-only, write-only, or read-write.

This is the code:

```
int File_Size = ...; 
char* Buffer = (char*)malloc(File_Size);

int Handle = open(File_Path,O_RDONLY);
read(Handle,Buffer,File_Size);
close(Handle);
```

Comment: Why no "fopen()"?

Comment: You may be the first one to complain about this! Taking care of both `\r\n` and `\n` is such a pain sometimes.

Comment: It isn't Windows doing this, it is the C library.

Comment: That's a feature, not a bug. The system's end-of-line marker (`"\r\n"` for Windows) is converted to a single newline (`'\n'`) character on input, and converted back on output, which frees you from having to worry about how each system represents end-of-line. Why can't you just work with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `O_RDONLY|O_BINARY`.

Comment: tks u so much, really save my day :)